# SQL Like statement not working in Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset, sql-like

```
Dim strText As String = tbRefine.Text
Dim sql As String = "SELECT user_name,forename,surname,game_cash,reg_group FROM tblGame WHERE user_name LIKE '" + strSearchText + "' & '*'"
Dim dsRefine As New DataSet
GetDataset(sql, "tblGame", dsRefine)

MsgBox(dsRefine.Tables("tblGame").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString)
```

This is not working, it crashes and says there is nothing in the dataset.
I know the dataset function works as its worked successfully before.
When i print out the sql statement into microsoft access it works fine. What am i doing wrong

Comment: Do you place values like '%somepattern%' in textbox?

Comment: We need to know the contents of tbRefine.Text (hopefully not a SQL injection exploit). And also the code in the GetDataSet method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
"SELECT user_name,forename,surname,game_cash,reg_group
 FROM tblGame
 WHERE user_name LIKE '%" + strSearchText + "%'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `RTRIM()` function in your line:

`Dim sql As String = "SELECT user_name,forename,surname,game_cash,reg_group 
                      FROM tblGame 
                      WHERE RTRIM(user_name) LIKE '" + strSearchText + "' & '*'"`

Answer (score 0):

What about leading or trailing % symbols in your like?

At the moment you will end up with a where clause like:

```
LIKE 'searchtext''*'
```

which looks a bit odd (I assume SQL server?).

Answer (score 0):

It's wiser to use SQL parameters as your method is open to SQL injection. The link below will help with how to format the SQL statement. I would also suggest doing it via a store procedure, but hats optional...

http://forums.asp.net/t/1256985.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think there's one more thing to be mentioned:
the "*" wildcard character works for the "Like" operator in VB/VBA/MS-Access, but not in T-SQL.
The correct wildcard character for the "Like" operator in T-SQL is "%".
That's why this T-SQL statement:

```
Select... WHERE ... LIKE 'sText*'
```

returned no data without any syntax error in MS-SQL(using T-SQL), but works in MS-Access.