# SQL query to search for a field by multiple values in same field

Tags: sql

For examples :

```
ID - Description

01 - Mix Black
02 - Mix Red
03 - Mix Blue
```

---

How I can write a query to show the field like `"Mi Bl"` in a query?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag it.

Comment: You need to edit your question so you're asking for what you actually need or you're going to keep getting answers to the question you asked. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE` with `%`:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE Description LIKE 'Mi%Bl%';
```

This query would give you these 2 results:

```
01 - Mix Black
03 - Mix Blue
```

---

`%` is a wildcard:

> The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters

[More information on `LIKE`.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: yes and thank you ,but I want to use it in vb project for text edit, so like this it not working

Comment: @AbbasHodroj You could try something like this in Visual Basic: `Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE Description LIKE 'Mi%Bl%'"`. Not my domain though. Just giving you something I came across that you might find useful. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583209/sql-like-statement-not-working-in-visual-basic

Comment: @AbbasHodroj: your comment makes no sense. The query solves the problem you stated in your question. I don't see why "a project for text edit" would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LIKE clause with wildcard characters.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Description LIKE 'Mi%Bl%';
```

This is SQL Server syntax, but any RDBMS will have a similar wildcard you can use.

Comment: yes and thank you ,but I want to use it in vb project for text edit, so like this it not working

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tablename 
WHERE `Description` LIKE 'Mi%Bl%';
```

'%' character is used to match any number(0, 1 or more) of characters.
So this will match to your below records and result set will be -

```
ID - Description
-------------------
01 - Mix Black
03 - Mix Blue
```

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL

Comment: yes and thank you ,but I want to use it in vb project for text edit, so like this it not working

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you please explain me what is invalid in this SQL?

Comment: Backticks are invalid in an SQL identifier and string literals need to be enclosed in single quotes. Double quotes are for identifiers `"Mi%Bl%"` is a column name in standard SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! Changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    FROM `table`
where Description like '%Mi% %Bl%'
```

Comment: yes and thank you ,but I want to use it in vb project for text edit, so like this it not working